# Matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question regarding matrix multiplication (multiply rows of the first matrix by the columns of the second).

Consider the two matrices $2 \times 2$ and $1 \times 2$

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}

I know that the dimensions are incompatible. I don't want to use the transpose of the second one which could be a solution though.

I was wondering whether it makes sense to add a zero dimension to the second matrix and make it $2 \times 2$  and then do the multiplication.

i.e.
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Then:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Is this mathematically acceptable?

Comment: Mathematically acceptable for what purpose?  You can indeed multiply those $2 \times 2$ matrices, but what do you want to do with the result?  You certainly can't say it's the product of the first matrix and the row vector.

Comment: This is just like multiplying an additional matrix in between:
$$\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3&2\end{pmatrix}$$
So alternatively, why not remove a column from the square matrix before multiplication?
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I have the two matrices $2 \times 2$ and $1 \times 2$ and I want to multiply them

Comment: @user161260 The question is, what do you want your multiplication result to mean?

Comment: I cannot remove columns or rows because I will lose data. I created this small example to got an idea how it's possible to multiply matrices with incompatible dimensions.

Comment: @peterwhy I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @user161260 I can define an alternative matrix multiplication to be
$$A\otimes B = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
for any dimensions, same or different. But for what meaning would the result give?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26894/discussion-between-user161260-and-peterwhy).

Comment: @user161260 everybody's been trying to ask you the same question: **why** do you want to multiply these incompatible matrices in this particular order?  What are you going to use the product for?

Comment: @user161260 perhaps you would be interested in the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using row-column product we have:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
9 & 14 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and this is the only way we can mulitply these matrices.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not commutative that's why I cannot use that Hint.

Comment: The ther way is not defined !

Comment: So there is no way to multiply the $2 \times 2$ matrix by the $1 \times 2$ matrix, right?

Comment: Yes!  No way to use the row-column rule in the order that you want.

Comment: Can I use other rule? Or it's simply impossible?

Comment: If you want you can define e column-row rule for multiplication, but the situation is simply symmetric. so it is  ''essentially'' impossible to define a multiplication on two sides for not square matrices.

Comment: How is that work? Actually it might be useful. So if I have two matrices $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ how can I define the column-row rule?

Comment: @user161260, not possible. It is like 1/0=?. There is no result.